# CannonJS Massive friction (sticky) on "east" facing walls while having a 0 friction

Tags: three.js, collision-detection, collision, detection, cannon.js

Currently in my game, I have a character with spheres as its collision box with 0 friction.

When moving into walls everything works smoothly as intended (I'm setting the character body's velocity)

UNLESS the wall is facing "east" in my game (-x axis direction)

**Things i've tried:**

I've placed a dynamic cube, that I can push around and if I try and push it from 3 of the faces i slide along them (intended) but the -x direction facing face my character wont slide along the wall, just simply sticks to it and I would have to back up in order to move.

here's where it gets strange, if I push the cube so that it rotates, the side that was previously sticky, now is smooth and perfect again, and the now new face that faces -x (east) direction is now sticky.

I've also tried using maps from other creators and for some reason the same thing happens.

https://youtu.be/f8Ku_ovWzf0 Youtube link example of me pushing a cube on 3 of working sides, and getting stuck on the -x axis face.  I then push the cube so that the sticky side is now facing a different axis and it works, and a different face is now sticky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem, The problem was with CannonJS i was sorting things based on [SAPBroadphase](https://pmndrs.github.io/cannon-es/docs/classes/SAPBroadphase.html). This will order the physics based on the x-axis by default. This would cause my player (in the physics world) to be simulated first, THEN the object it collides with causing it to stick, rather than slide.

The fix was to order the player to be the last simulated object.